# how to connect SQL-Server database with Oracle Enterprise Repository

Tags: sql-server, oracle, repository, soa, enterprise

My dept wants to keep using a homegrown ASP application that runs off a SQL-Server database, but we also want to take advantage of the governance capabilities and that slick navigator in Oracle Enterprise Repository.  Is it possible to integrate an OER database with an un-normalized SQL-Server database?

I don't mean like a one-shot migration from SQL to OER. I'm looking for an adapter or something that would allow use of both OER and the ASP application on an ongoing basis?

I don't want to do a tightly coupled solution that involves a lot of coding of .bat files.  I'd rather do something that takes advantage of already existing connectors and adapters, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

OER does support SQL Server as the backend already - take a look at the OER Installation Guide. Great idea to use OER - we find it to be a very powerful and flexible tool for Governance, and I hear Oracle is investing a lot in it for future versions.